# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox looping though links

Tags: perl, web-scraping, www-mechanize, www-mechanize-firefox

I am using a `foreach` to loop through links. Do I need a `$mech->back();` to continue the loop or is that implicit.

Furthermore do I need a separate `$mech2` object for nested for each loops?

The code I currently have gets stuck (it does not complete) and ends on the first page where `td#tabcolor3` is not found.

```
foreach my $sector ($mech->selector('a.link2'))
{
    $mech->follow_link($sector);

    foreach my $place ($mech->selector('td#tabcolor3'))
    {
            if (($mech->selector('td#tabcolor3', all=>1)) >= 1)
    {
        $mech->follow_link($place);
            print $_->{innerHTML}, '\n'
            for $mech->selector('td.dataCell');
        $mech->back();
    }
    else
    {
        $mech->back();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access information from a page when it is no longer on display. However, the way `foreach` works is to build the list *first* before it is iterated through, so the code you have written should be fine.

There is no need for the call to `back` as the links are absolute. If you had used `click` then there must be a link in the page to click on, but with `follow_link` all you are doing is going to a new URL.

There is also no need to check the number of links to follow, as a `for` loop over an empty list will simply not be executed.

To make things clearer I suggest that you assign the results of `selector` to an array before the loop.

Like this

```
my @sectors = $mech->selector('a.link2');
for my $sector (@sectors) {

    $mech->follow_link($sector);

    my @places = $mech->selector('td#tabcolor3');
    for my $place (@places) {

        $mech->follow_link($place);

        print $_->{innerHTML}, '\n' for $mech->selector('td.dataCell');
    }
}
```

**Update**

My apologies. It seems that `follow_link` is finicky and needs to follow a link *on the current page*.

I suggest that you extract the `href` attribute from each link and use `get` instead of `follow_link`.

```
my @selectors = map $_->{href}, $mech->selector('a.link2');
for my $selector (@selectors) {

    $mech->get($selector);

    my @places = map $_->{href}, $mech->selector('td#tabcolor3');
    for my $place (@places) {

        $mech->get($place);

        print $_->{innerHTML}, '\n' for $mech->selector('td.dataCell');
    }
}
```

Please let me know whether this works on the site you are connecting to.

Comment: Thanks much more elegant solution. I am getting a Mozrepl::RemoteObject: TypeError - can't access dead object at this line := $mech->follow_link($share); #it is shown above...I think there is a problem with the nested for...do I need a seperate mech object as previous answer suggested?

Comment: Sorry the line is: $mech->follow_link($place);

Comment: From the [*latest modifications list*](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CORION/WWW-Mechanize-Firefox-0.70/Changes) it looks like the "dead object" problem started with Firefox 15. I have updated my solution to show an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, unfrtunately this also gives a dead object error in the ~/MozRepl/RemoteObject.pm line 1530. It does only the first iteration...the error comes then it print the output

Comment: Maybe it is too late even to extract the value of  `href`. I have edited my solution again slightly to fetch the `href` link while the page is displayed. Please see if it works now.

Comment: Are you sure you want to follow the link of a `<td>` element? I think an `href` attribute on a `td` is illegal.

Comment: Incredible!!! Thanks so much it's working. I'm stoked. Yes I changed the 'td' to 'a[name=tranlist]' as you suggested in my other question. So as a rule of thumb mechanize::Firefox only uses what is on the current page

Comment: Objects that are an instance of `MozRepl::RemoteObject::Instance are only valid until the browser loads another page. (See what class things are by `print`ing them). The things in the list that `selector` returns are like this, but you can interrogate them for information that will not change, like the `href` attribute here which is just a string.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use separate $mech object for this:

```
foreach my $sector ($mech->selector('a.link2'))
{
    my $mech = $mech->clone();
    $mech->follow_link($sector);

    foreach my $place ($mech->selector('td#tabcolor3'))
    {
            if (($mech->selector('td#tabcolor3', all=>1)) >= 1)
    {
            my $mech = $mech->clone();
            $mech->follow_link($place);
            print $_->{innerHTML}, '\n'
            for $mech->selector('td.dataCell');
        #$mech->back();
    }
#    else
#    {
#        $mech->back();
#    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you recommend multiple Mechanize objects?

Comment: Because I can easy change this code to use with several threads for example. I'm talking about classic WWW::Mechanize of course not a Firefox.

Comment: The `clone` method is listed in the module documentation under *Functions that will likely never be implemented*. Presumably you haven;t tested your code?

Answer (score 0):

I am using WWW:Mechanize::Firefox to loop over a bunch of URLs with loads of Javascript. The page does not render immediately so need test if a particular page element is visible (similar to suggestion in Mechanize::Firefox documentation except 2 xpaths in the test) before deciding next action.

The page eventually renders a xpath to 'no info' or some wanted stuff after about 2-3 seconds. If no info we go to next URL. I think there is some sort of race condition with both xpaths not existing at once causing the **`MozRepl::RemoteObject: TypeError: can't access dead object`** error intermittently (at the `sleep 1` in the loop oddly enough).

My solution that seems to work/improve reliability is to enclose all the `$mech->get`and`$mech->is_visible` in an `eval{};` like this:

```
eval{ 
  $mech->get("$url");
  $retries = 15; #test to see if element visible = page complete
  while ($retries-- and ! $mech->is_visible( xpath => $xpath_btn ) and  ! $mech->is_visible( xpath => $xpath_no_info )){
    sleep 1;
  };
  last if($mech->is_visible( xpath => $xpath_no_info) ); #skip rest if no info page
};
```

Others might suggest improvements on this.